# is it possible to change angle of scales in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

As the question states, is that possible to change the angle of the text of a scale in `ggplot` ?

I mean, I  would like the labels used on the x axis to be rotated by 90 degrees.

You can apparently use `angle` with a legend but it doesn't seems to work for a scale.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use:

```
 + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90))
```

Since version 0.9.2, `opts` has been [replaced](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`:

```
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Comment: Also, it's always a good idea to point people toward the pretty extensive set of examples in `?opts` (in the more recent versions of ggplot2) that demonstrate most of the stuff you can customize.

Comment: @joran Thanks for the pro-tip. I haven't looked at those since the update!  They're excellent now.